# Online design/rendering of graphs and illustrations in your posts?

Tags: discussion, formatting

How do you design and manage graphs and illustrations in your posts, that cannot be done by mathjax?

For example, for graphs, I have begun using [Erdos](http://www.kidstrythisathome.com/2011/09/erdos-a-javascript-interface-to-create-graphviz-charts/) ([demo](http://sandbox.kidstrythisathome.com/erdos/)), an interface to Google Charts API for rendering graphviz (I'd preveiously used [this graphviz-dev tool](http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com/), but the server periodically fails). Are there any other such gems (both online or offline)? What about doodling tools?

Comment: I've used Mathematica, it's pretty fast to draw graphs and say highlight or color vertices or edges.

Comment: One thing to always keep in mind is visual impairments; don't use color alone to distinguish elements of your graphics! If in doubt, inspect your graphic with a simulator, e.g. [this one](http://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/).

Comment: @Raphael ah thanks, I was looking for a tool like that recently.

Comment: asked about misc graph pkgs on the new [softwarerecs.se] site but it got closed quickly. maybe someone else can ask better

Answer (score 4):

I have come to rely [quite heavily](http://akerbos.github.io/sesketches/) on [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/), a powerful graphical library for LaTeX.

I write code like

```
%p% \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
  \node[draw, circle] (s) at (00,15) {$s$};
  \node[draw, circle] (a) at (15,15) {$a$};
  \node[draw, circle] (b) at (15,00) {$b$};
  \node[draw, circle] (t) at (00,00) {$t$};

  \path[->] (s) edge node {$1$} (a)
            (s) edge node {$2$} (t)
            (a) edge node {$1$} (b)
            (b) edge node {$1$} (t);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

in a file, translate it with [tikz2png](https://github.com/akerbos/scripts/blob/master/tikz2png) and upload to SE:

[image]

TikZ has quite a learning curve but is worth the effort (if you use it to write articles or RPG material, too). Don't try anything without [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). In case of trouble, [tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) is by far the best resource, both in terms of available knowledge and responses to new questions.